# TD fijo en ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Tengo lo siguiente:

mi app.css

```
.fijar-headcol {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex !important;
  width:100px;
}
```

mi index.html

```
<div style="height:500px; overflow: auto;">
  <tr ng-repeat="dat in datos">
    <td class="fijar-headcol">{{dat.title}}</td>
    <td>{{dat.dato1}}</td>
    <td>{{dat.dato2}}</td>
    <td>{{dat.dato3}}</td>
    <td>....</td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

el problema es que el td que contiene dato 1, no sale porque lo esta tapando el primer td que contiene el titulo

Aqui el ejemplo:

```css
.fijar-headcol {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  /* Centramos */
  display: flex !important;
/*   justify-content: center; */
/*   align-items: center; */
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:500px; overflow: auto;">
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="fijar-headcol">dat.title</td>
    <td>dat.dato1</td>
    <td>dat.dato2</td>
    <td>dat.dato3</td>
    <td>dat.dato1</td>
    <td>dat.dato2</td>
    <td>dat.dato3</td>
    <td>....</td>
    <td>dat.dato1</td>
    <td>dat.dato2</td>
    <td>dat.dato3</td>
    <td>dat.dato1</td>
    <td>dat.dato2</td>
    <td>dat.dato3</td>
    <td>dat.dato1</td>
    <td>dat.dato2</td>
    <td>dat.dato3</td>
    <td>....</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: el problema no son los td, angularjs hace un render muy extraño, la solucion que encontre mas efectiva, es ocultar toda la tabla, componente, div , entre otros, y mostrarla al final de la carga, asi los estilos que progrmas en angularjs no se te perderan, y te lo digo me meti en el inspector y veia si mis estilos estaban cargados y estaban por alguna razon no lo tomaba

Comment: Has cambiado totalmentre la pregunta y ahora el título no se corresponde, deberías editarlo también

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes indicar que el 2ndo hijo, `td:nth-child(2)` tenga un `padding-left` suficiente como para que no se solapen:

```
td:nth-child(2){

    padding-left:100px;

}
```

```css
.fijar-headcol {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  /* Centramos */
  display: flex !important;
  /*   justify-content: center; */
  /*   align-items: center; */
  width: 100px;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  padding-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:500px; overflow: auto;">
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td class="fijar-headcol">dat.title</td>
      <td>dat.dato1</td>
      <td>dat.dato2</td>
      <td>dat.dato3</td>
      <td>dat.dato1</td>
      <td>dat.dato2</td>
      <td>dat.dato3</td>
      <td>....</td>
      <td>dat.dato1</td>
      <td>dat.dato2</td>
      <td>dat.dato3</td>
      <td>dat.dato1</td>
      <td>dat.dato2</td>
      <td>dat.dato3</td>
      <td>dat.dato1</td>
      <td>dat.dato2</td>
      <td>dat.dato3</td>
      <td>....</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```